# ER modeling account transaction with two participants

Tags: entity-relationship

Hello I need help with this modeling

a transaction can have one or two participants, and one or more statements can have that transaction.
But I need to somehow know who owns the transaction and who receives the transaction
An example :
the participant who owns the transaction sends 100 dollars, I need to somehow show that he is losing 100 dollars and the other participant of the transaction receiving 100 dollars

[image]

but I’m not able to imagine how I can do that, identify in the transaction who is the origin and the destination and the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, `transaction_participants.from_id` is the "owner" (payer) and `transaction_participants.to_id` is the receiver. Multiple records in `transaction_participants` for single transaction could mean some kind of multi-payment for several receivers.

Concerning how to get the amount of payments, for example amount of payments sent from certain account: you start with rows from `transaction_participants` where `from_id` is the account ID, and via `transactions_has_transaction_participants` you get to `transactions.amount`, where the total amount of transaction is stored.

Comment: I think so too, but I have some difficulty having the amount that came out of the source account and the amount that came into the destination account.

Comment: @Ming I think this could be done easily, please see my edited answer.